# R Text Mining - the most frequent word in string across entire data frame

Tags: r, tm, word-frequency

I am struggling to grasp text mining and determine word frequencies. I am just starting to have an understanding of R and its packages and I just find out about tm (after reading a while I have a feeling that this might solve my problem).

My question is: how can I determine the two most frequently used in a string across the entire column?

I have the following example:

```
    structure(list(Location = c("Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "Texas", "Texas", "Texas", 
"Texas", "Texas"), Code = c(4450L, 4450L, 4450L, 4450L, 4450L, 
4450L, 4450L, 4450L, 4450L, 4410L, 4410L, 4410L, 4410L, 4410L
), Description = c("LABOR - CROSSOVER BOARD BRACKET", "LABOR - CROWN DOOR GASKET", 
"LABOR - CROWN DOOR GASKET - APPLY 4' NEW GASKET AND RE-APPLY", 
"LABOR - CUSHIONING DEVICE - END OF CAR CUSTOMER SUPPLIED MATERIAL", 
"LABOR - DOOR EDGE", "LABOR - DOOR GASKET, CROWN CORNER", "LABOR - DOOR LOCK POCKET STG", 
"LABOR - DOOR LOCK RECEPTICALS STG", "LABOR - DOOR LOCK STG", 
"BOLT, HT, UNDER 5/8\"\" DIA & 6\"\" - SIDE POST", "BOLT, HT, UNDER 5/8\"\" DIA & 6\"\" - TRAINLINE TROLLEY", 
"BOLT,HT,5/8 IN.DIA.OR LESS UNDER 6\"\" LONG - BRAKE STEP", "BOLT,HT,5/8 IN.DIA.OR LESS UNDER 6\"\" LONG - CROSSOVER BOARD", 
"BOLT,HT,5/8 IN.DIA.OR LESS UNDER 6\"\" LONG - CROSSOVER BOARD BRACKET"
), `Desired Description Based on frequency` = c("Labor - CROWN DOOR GASKET", 
"Labor - CROWN DOOR GASKET", "Labor - CROWN DOOR GASKET", "Labor - DOOR LOCK", 
"Labor - DOOR LOCK", "Labor - DOOR LOCK", "Labor - DOOR LOCK", 
"Labor - DOOR LOCK", "Labor - DOOR LOCK", "Bolt - HT", "Bolt - HT", 
"Bolt - HT", "Bolt - HT", "Bolt - HT")), .Names = c("Location", 
"Code", "Description", "Desired Description Based on frequency"
), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the end I wish I could add this column:

```
Desired Description Based on frequency
Labor - CROWN DOOR GASKET
Labor - CROWN DOOR GASKET
Labor - CROWN DOOR GASKET
Labor - DOOR LOCK
Labor - DOOR LOCK
Labor - DOOR LOCK
Labor - DOOR LOCK
Labor - DOOR LOCK
Labor - DOOR LOCK
Bolt - HT
Bolt - HT
Bolt - HT
Bolt - HT
Bolt - HT
```

Basically I want to evaluate all the 4450 or 4410s and see out of all the description in the table, which the most common and add that as a column. Another condition would be based on the location. Can someone please help me with a simple example?

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use `dput` to provide your input data and the desired output data frame (liked asked in the R info - hover over the tag).

Comment: Thank you Luke. My input data is huge so I just took a small fraction of it to show of simple example of what I wish of achieve. I can provide more info if it's not clear enough.

Comment: I meant: please edit your post and replace the data sample by `dput(datasample)` - this makes it easy to import the sample into an R session and play/experiment with it. The way you provided it, one would need to place a delimiter to import it.

Comment: Thank you Luke. I have edited the post. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Thanks, better in terms of reproducibility. However, However, there's no magic function that's spits out your desired output. You prly have to normalize your strings, group them, find a weighting/ranking scheme to select the most descriptive terms (maybe tfidf) and assign those to your data frame columns. All in all, that's beyond the scope of SO (imho).

Comment: You're the man, Luke! If you could help me assign the result to my data frame columns, I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a one-size-fits-it-all-solution to your problem. (Beginning with the fact that there's no exact rule on which or how many words to take for the description.) However, here are two quick&dirty approaches, which might be helpful as a starting point:

```
library(tm)
txts <- gsub("[^A-Z]", " ", df$Description)
groups <- paste(df$Location, df$Code)

# 1
opts <- list(tolower=F, removePunctuation=TRUE, wordLengths=c(2, Inf))
lst <- split(txts, groups)
res <- sapply(lst, function(x) { 
  freq <- termFreq(paste(x, collapse=" "), opts)/length(x)
  paste(names(freq[rank(-freq, ties.method = "first")<=3]), collapse = " - ")
})
rep(res, lengths(lst))

# 2 
lst <- lapply(strsplit(txts, "\\s+"), function(x) x[1:min(c(3,length(x)))] )
lst <- split(lst, groups)
n <- lengths(lst)
lst <- mapply("/", lapply(lst, function(x) sort(table(unlist(x)), decreasing = T)), n)
rep(sapply(lst, function(x) paste(names(x)[x>=.5], collapse=" - ")), n)
```

Comment: Luke, you're a genius! Thank you so much for this awesome solution. I wouldn't figure it out in ages. I really appreciate your help. The second approached worked best for me. Can you please show me how can I add the result from "rep" as a new column in my original df? I just didn't find a way yet. Thanks again for being so helpful.

Comment: @iCosmin Like `df$myResult <- rep(...)`?

Comment: Precisely. In the meantime I've achieved the same result by using mutate. Your solution works perfectly on the sample data but when I apply it to my entire data set (271231 obs.) it seems like the grouping part is not working anymore. When I print every step, everything is exactly the same as in our example but if I take a closer look, the result is actually returning the most frequent words in the description but it doesn't apply the location condition. Is there a workaround? If I change the order in groups (groups <- paste(df$Code, df$Location) I get a different result. Please help.

Comment: I have noticed that if I print "lst" and "rep", the output is correct in the console. The whole grouping breaks when adding the result as a new column to the df. It's so frustrating because we are almost there but the final step just cancels the whole effort. :(

Comment: @iCosmin Maybe because of the ordering? What about `df$description  <- sapply(lst, function(x) paste(names(x)[x>=.5], collapse=" - "))[groups]`?

Comment: EXCELLENT! That's it! I can't believe we finally did it. Thank you so much Luke. There's one last thing that I need your help with and it's case closed. How can we keep the original order of the words in the description? E.g.: even though the description is "Heat and Straighten" I end up with "and Heat Straighten". It's not based on the frequency it occurs. The same description only appears twice and it still rearranges the wording. If you could provide a solution for keeping the original order of the words, hats off to you Sir!

Comment: @iCosmin If I see that right, keeping the original order will not work with the two approaches.

Comment: Can you help me with a slightly different approach? I am happy with the result but I just need it in a readable order. I can't think of anything so nice a simple like you have.